# Submit function when the same form is on the page twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below JavaScript `submit` function for a form that works fine. But when the form is on the page twice it only works for the first form and not for the second. I presume I need to use something with `this` so it only works on the active form?

HTML:

```
<form action="resultsnew.php" method="get" style="margin-bottom: 0" class="store-search-form">
    <input type="text" name="d" value="Enter Postcode..." onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Enter Postcode...':this.value;" class="find-form-input field store-search-postcode" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="java" value="Search" class="button" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.store-search-form').submit(function() {
    //get the input's value
    var postcodeinput = $('.store-search-postcode').val();

    //remove spaces
    postcodeinput = postcodeinput.replace(/\s/g, '');

    //if valid postcode length trim it down
    if (postcodeinput.length >= 5 && postcodeinput.length <= 7) {

      //set the input's value
      $('.store-search-postcode').val(postcodeinput.substring(0,postcodeinput.length - 3));
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML

Comment: well you do not select the fields in the form that is being submitted, you are selecting the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the `input` that is in each form using `$(this).find('.store-search-postcode')` and then use that reference:

```
$('.store-search-form').submit(function() {
  //get the input
  var postcodeinput = $(this).find('.store-search-postcode');
  //get the input's value
  var postcode = postcodeinput.val();
  //remove spaces
  postcode = postcode.replace(/\s/g, '');
  //if valid postcode length trim it down
  if (postcode.length >= 5 && postcode.length <= 7) {
    //set the input's value
    postcodeinput.val(postcode.substring(0, postcode.length - 3));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do your searching relative to `$(this)` via [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), i.e., change this:

```
var postcodeinput = $('.store-search-postcode').val();
```

to this:

```
var $this = $(this);
// ...
var postcodeinput = $this.find('.store-search-postcode').val();
```

(And in the other places you use it.)

Remember, within an event handler, `this` refers to the element the handler was hooked up to. `$(this)` creates a jQuery instance for that element. And then `find` searches within that element's descendants.